# What is the distribution of closest vertex to normal random variable on simplex?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is a normal random variable on the "extended $n-1$-simplex" (for want of a better name) $E_{n-1} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} : \sum  x_i = 1\}$.  Further suppose that the covariance of $X$ is small enough that with very high probability $X$ lies in the $n-1$-simplex $S_{n-1} = \{ x \in E_{n-1} : 0 \le x_i \le 1 \}$.

To each observation of $X$ I can assign its "dominant vertex" under the mapping $c : S_n \to \{ 0, \ldots, n \}$ given by $c(x) = i$ when $x_i \ge x_j$ for all $j$.  (I'm not interested in ties, since they occur with probability zero, and if $x \in S_{n-1}$ then $c(x)$ is the closet vertex to $x$ under any $p$-norm, I believe.)

How can I efficiently (in the computational sense) approximate the distribution of $c(X)$?

Similarly, suppose $Y$ is a normal random variable on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with covariance small enough that with very high probability $Y$ lies in the $n$-cube $C_n = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : 0 \le x_i \le 1 \}$.  How can I efficiently approximate the distribution of $c(Y)$?

If the question is easier to answer for some other reasonably symmetric, reasonably diffuse distribution then that would be an acceptable answer too.

Comment: Can you explain to me why the distribution of $c(X)$ is not uniform on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ by a simple symmetry argument ?

Comment: The hypothesis is that $X$ is normal, but says nothing about what its mean and variance are!